Unable to convert doclaynet dataset to yolo compatible format
I was trying to train yolo version 8 on doclaynet dataset.But I'm unable to convert the arrow files to the yolo compatible format.
As yolo expects images and labels separately, I'm unable to achieve that.
I was following this github repository: https://github.com/LynnHaDo/Document-Layout-Analysis
I've been downloading doclaynet dataset from here: https://huggingface.co/datasets/ds4sd/DocLayNet
Can anyone help me convert doclaynet dataset arrow files to yolo compatible format. Or can provide some resources which allow downloading doclaynet dataset with images and labels separately.
